# Mongoose Unilevel Query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I do unilevel query with mongoose.

Example collection :

| ID | NAME | PARENT ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | 0 |
| 2 | Michael | 1 |
| 3 | George | 2 |
| 4 | Yuri | 1 |

Example output :

```
[{ id:1, name:Alex, parentId:0},{ id:2, Michael, parentId:1},{ id:3, name:George, parentId:2},{ id:4, name:Yuri, parentId:1}]
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: I don't know what a "unilevel query" is, but isn't your example output the same thing as your example collection?

Comment: For example I wanna query parentId=2 and I need output parentId 2 hierarchy.

Comment: Do you think [`"$graphLookup"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes but I can get all records. I wanna spesific user hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand the challenge, but I thought this might help, or maybe just a start.  The output is a bit "raw", but more stages could be added to the pipeline to customize it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // start with somebody, or in this case
    // somebody's parentId
    "$match": {
      "parentId": 2
    }
  },
  {
    // go all the way up the parent tree
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$parentId",
      "connectFromField": "parentId",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "depthField": "depth",
      "as": "parents"
    }
  }
])
```

Example output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "George",
    "parentId": 2,
    "parents": [
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "depth": NumberLong(0),
        "name": "Michael",
        "parentId": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "depth": NumberLong(1),
        "name": "Alex",
        "parentId": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0apP6nOxjc0).